# Scaling a system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I can't understand a scaling that has been made: Consider the 1D R-D-system $$\epsilon\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\epsilon^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+f(u,v)\\\epsilon\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=D \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}-f(u,v)$$ with $u(x,t), v(x,t)$. Introduce a stretched coordinate $\xi:=\frac{x-\phi(t)}{\epsilon}$ with some function $\phi(t)$. Assume $$u(x,t) = U(\xi, t), v(x,t)=V(\xi,t)$$
By substituting the new scaling into the system above one obtains $$\epsilon\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi}= \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial \xi^2}+f(U,V)\\\epsilon\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \xi}= D\epsilon^{-2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \xi^2}-f(U,V).$$ How? I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the chain rule, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial\xi}{\partial x}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \frac{\partial U}{\partial\xi}, \\
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial \xi^2}, \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t}\frac{\partial U}{\partial\xi} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial t}.
\end{align}
Plugging these formulas in the PDE for $u$ we obtain
$$ \varepsilon \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\frac{\partial U}{\partial\xi} = \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial\xi^2} + f(U,V).$$
Can you figure out the equation for $V$ by yourself from here?

Comment: Thank you!! I've got one question: why $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial\xi}{\partial {\color{red} t}}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi}$ and not  $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial\xi}{\partial {\color{red} x}}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi}$?

Comment: Good catch, of course it should be $\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial x}$ in that formula, otherwise there would be an extra $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}$ coming from the time derivative.